# How can I lock a file to protect against multiple ajax requests reading/writing the same file?

Tags: php, ajax, file, asynchronous, file-locking

I am currently trying to prevent a file from being read if it already exists and has content in it. I am using the `flock` method to try and prevent other instances of the script running from accessing it, but it is not working. This is only an issue with servers with multiple cores.

```php
while ($aEvent = current($aEvents)){
    $sLockFile = '/var/tmp/'.md5($aEvent['id']).'.LCK';
    $oFile = fopen($sLockFile, 'c+');
    if (flock($oFile, LOCK_EX) && fgets($oFile) == '') {
        fwrite($oFile, 'locked');
        fclose($oFile);
    } else {
        fclose($oFile);
        next($aEvents);
        continue;
    }
    /*
     * Do stuff here.
     */
    next($aEvents);
}
```

So from this code, I expect that a file is created, locked, and written to, and any request that tries to subsequently read/write the file is either stopped at the `flock` call or the empty check. When in reality it seems like if the code is hit with enough ajax requests at the same time, the same file is being created/overwritten multiple times. Is there any way to keep PHP thread safe?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to add the `LOCK_NB` bit to your `flock` call. From [the flock docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php):

> By default, this function will block until the requested lock is acquired; this may be controlled with the LOCK_NB option

Your code will block on each call to `flock` until a lock can be acquired. It sounds like you want to skip to the `else` block if a lock exists. If so, you want to do this in your code:

```
<?php
if (flock($oFile, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB) && fgets($oFile) == '')
...
```

Comment: Will try that and report back with the results. But from my understanding of that doc block, by default it blocks until it locks. The LOCK_NB option would disable that wouldn't it?

Comment: Yup, as I expected it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Yeah, are you trying to block until you get a lock, or fail fast into the else block? I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'd be okay with either one as long as the file gets accessed only once.